# conditional match operation in spring mongo db

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I using below MatchOperation to match certain criteria in Spring data Mongodb

```
MatchOperation propertyMatchOperation = Aggregation.match(
    Criteria.
            where("abc1").is(abcVal1)
            .and("abc2").is(abcVal2)
            .and("abc3").is(abcVal3)
            .and("abc4").is(abcVal4)
            .and("abc5").is(abcVal5)
);
```

When some value is `null` or `""`, it checks for `""` value in mongodb, while that parameter should not be included in the query.

Suppose , `abcVal3` is `null`, then then above match operation will search for only `null` value in parameter and it sends zero results, even if other criteria are matching.

Is there any way to make it conditional exclusive or inclusive?

Comment: I think it won't be a problem in matching. If the `abc3`  is `null`, other 4 variables satisfy (because of `AND`) your condition, it will return the matching data

Comment: it matches like 
"abc1" :"first", "abc2" : "second" , "abc3" :"third" , "abc4" : "" , "abc5" : "". 
So, if i have to mach first, second, third irrespective of values of abc4 and abc5, it is not happening. It queries for abc4 and abc4 with value "" .

Comment: Does that mean, you send `abc1="first"` , `abc2="second"`,  `abc3="third"`, `abc4=null` , `abc5=null` ? Or are you sending `""` for `null` ?

Comment: yes, cause default vault value will be null or "".